# Why are the scala compiler arguments passed to my program?

Tags: scala, maven, command-line-arguments

I have the following in my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
      <args>
        <arg>-unchecked</arg>
        <arg>-deprecation</arg>
      </args>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My main object is:

```
object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    args.foreach(println)
  }
}
```

And it prints:

```
$ mvn scala:run -DaddArgs='hello|world'
[...]
-unchecked
-deprecation
hello
world
```

Why? The first two are intended to be the compiler arguments (and they actually work as such), and I don't want to see them in my program!

What can I do to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: seems strange effectively. You should consider using sbt instead.

Comment: @David I tried it, but it seems not as simple as it is named :) I think I'll post another question regarding sbt.

Comment: I've found this faulty approach in the last section of this page: http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/maven-scala-plugin/example_compile.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to try using sbt, a simple `build.sbt` in your project root :

```
name := "test"

version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.9.1"
```

then you can run it

```
% xsbt
> run Hello World
...
Hello
World
```

Comment: Yeah, I know this, thanks. My problems with sbt were a bit deeper and involved library dependencies. Nevermind :)

Comment: So, finally I started using SBT, so this one is accepted. Thanks!